Need help to convert each element of a list to dictionary
I have a list in Scala, where the structure of the list is:
['A:abc','B:hgfff', 'C':khfas' ...] it's a big list.
I want to convert it to a dictionary like:
d={'A':'abc','B':'hgfff','C':'khfas'}
Kindly help with the Scala code to get it
Expecting Scala code to complete it.

What did you try so far? What's blocking you? SO is supposed to give answers to a specific problem, not a place to ask for code from a spec.

val input = List("A:abc","B:hgfff", "C:khfas")

val m = input.collect {
  case s"${key}:${value}" => key -> value
}.toMap

// val m: Map[String, String] = Map(A -> abc, B -> hgfff, C -> khfas)


You could additionally remove flatMap, Option and None if you used .collect { s"$key:$value" => key -> value }.

If it is a big list then using input.view might help performance as without that it will create a new List and then convert it to a Map.

object ListToMap {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val list = List("A:abc", "B:hgfff", "C:khfas")  // your list

    val map = list.map { s =>
      val Array(key, value) = s.split(":")
      key -> value
    }.toMap

    println(map)  // Output: Map(A -> abc, B -> hgfff, C -> khfas)
  }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
